# Open Outlook.exe from cmd with email, subject and body

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, outlook

I'm trying to open Microsoft Outlook 2016 from cmd, but i'd like for the email, subject and body to be filled with some data.
I tried this command both in a visualstudio project through a system() command and directly from cmd, but the command only fills the email and doesn't consider the others.

```
cmd /c OUTLOOK.EXE /c ipm.note /m prova@gmail.it&subject=Questo%20è%20un%20oggetto&body=Questo%20è%20il%20corpo
```

This is the command I'm trying to pass, and the only error message I get from the cmd is that subject and body are not verified commands, but I see that everyone uses them.

Comment: The command you're trying to run, i.e after `/c` should be doublequoted, to protect the obviously poisonous characters. You may even need to use nested doublequotes, around your `/m` option.

Comment: This may be helpful information to those looking at this question. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6#ID0EAABAAA=Outlook